# import a .C api file in Python

Tags: python, c, macos, dll, ctypes

For a project I want to implement a c file in python. It is library for the MCP2210. I found it on http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP2210_linux_library.zip.

how do I implement this into a python code so i can access the methods that are written in the library? 
I knew there is something like ctypes.DLL but i use a mac to program. .DLL is for windows.

Comment: ctypes also works for Mac OS or Linux although it uses the term "DLL".

Comment: I tried it with ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("path to dll") but he give an error with unknown file type

Comment: Maybe the library wasn't compiled correctly for Mac OS.